# HTML div 'underlapping' the div below it

Tags: html, css

I have an issue on a test web-page i'm creating for practice where i have two div elements one above the other, however the top one (.item in the CSS) is 'under lapping' the bottom one (.wide and .img-span in the css) and sticks out  on the other-side for some reason. I have fiddled around with my CSS and HTML for a while and i cant fix it.

CSS:

```
.item {
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.item p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.img-span {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.wide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="first" class="item">
        <p class="para">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime distinctio sed officia, nam iure quam necessitatibus nobis non, aut quaerat autem. Quam mollitia, fugiat amet veritatis, voluptate earum quidem et! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci ex earum impedit ipsum consequatur dolor doloremque eum. Sed fugit dolor maiores pariatur nesciunt iste cupiditate consequuntur, dolore alias numquam voluptatum!
        </p>
   </div>
   <div id="img-span">
       <img src="img/board-911636.jpg" class="wide">
   </div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `display: block` on the `img` fixes your problem.

Comment: oh that was simple thanks alot. Ill edit the original post so that context is kept when the website link doesn't work. Thanks alot :)